Why is my bean not replaced with @MockBean?
I have an integration test with @MockBean, but the bean is not replaced. The real bean is used.   Why is the bean not replaced?
Application code
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyListener {

  private final AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
  private final MyService myService;

  @RabbitListener(queues = "q_request")
  public void listen(@Payload final String value) {
    log.info("Listener: {}, {}", myService.hashCode(), value);
    final String result = myService.get(value);
    amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("test", "response", result);
  }
}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

  public String get(final String value) {
    log.info("Service: {}, {} ", this.hashCode(), value);
    return "realService";
  }
}

Test code
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
class ApplicationTest {

  @Test
  void testContextLoads() {}
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@Slf4j
class MyListenerTest {

  @Autowired private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
  @MockBean MyService myService;

  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestRabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue responseQueue() {
      return new Queue("q_response", false, false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding responseBinding(final DirectExchange directExchange, final Queue responseQueue) {
      return BindingBuilder.bind(responseQueue).to(directExchange).with("response");
    }
  }

  @Test
  void testMessaging() {

    log.info(
        "Test: {}, {}, {}",
        myService.hashCode(),
        mockingDetails(myService).isMock(),
        mockingDetails(myService).isSpy());

    when(myService.get("value")).thenReturn("result");

    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("test", "request", "value");

    final Message message = rabbitTemplate.receive("q_response", 10000);
    assertNotNull(message);
    verify(myService).get("value");
  }
}

Logs
The log of MyListenerTest shows that the bean is a mock (no spy) in my test class, but the real bean is executed.
2024-08-08T11:01:31.861Z  INFO 105 --- [           main] test.MyListenerTest                      : Started MyListenerTest in 0.818 seconds (process running for 4.28)
2024-08-08T11:01:31.877Z  INFO 105 --- [           main] test.MyListenerTest                      : Test: 1719990258, true, false
2024-08-08T11:01:31.952Z  INFO 105 --- [ntContainer#0-1] test.MyListener                          : Listener: 63583816, value
2024-08-08T11:01:31.953Z  INFO 105 --- [ntContainer#0-1] test.MyService                           : Service: 63583816, value 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.982 s <<< FAILURE! - in test.MyListenerTest
[ERROR] test.MyListenerTest.testMessaging  Time elapsed: 0.126 s  <<< FAILURE!
Wanted but not invoked:
myService bean.get("value");
-> at test.MyService.get(MyService.java:15)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
    at test.MyService.get(MyService.java:15)
    at test.MyListenerTest.testMessaging(MyListenerTest.java:62)

Environment

Java 17
Spring Boot 3.1.9
Maven

Research

The tests passed in the last two years without a problem, but suddenly the test execution order changed (maybe a change in the dockerized build environment).

If I change the name of the tests to change the order of test execution, the tests all pass.

It looks like the context was cached, but it should not be cached, see Context Caching:


contextCustomizers (from ContextCustomizerFactory) – this includes @DynamicPropertySource methods as well as various features from Spring Boot’s testing support such as @MockBean and @SpyBean.



The bean should be replaced, see Annotation Interface MockBean:

Mocks can be registered by type or by bean name. When registered by type, any existing single bean of a matching type (including subclasses) in the context will be replaced by the mock. When registered by name, an existing bean can be specifically targeted for replacement by a mock. In either case, if no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.


@TestConfiguration doesn't change the application configuration and therefore it seems to not prevent context caching, see Detecting Test Configuration:

If you want to customize the primary configuration, you can use a nested @TestConfiguration class. Unlike a nested @Configuration class, which would be used instead of your application’s primary configuration, a nested @TestConfiguration class is used in addition to your application’s primary configuration.


I could add @DirtiesContext to ApplicationTest to prevent context caching, see Annotation Interface DirtiesContext:

Test annotation which indicates that the ApplicationContext associated with a test is dirty and should therefore be closed and removed from the context cache.

But if the execution order changed again (for example with a new test) I had to move @DirtiesContext to new test to make sure, that MyListenerTest is still working.

I added @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS) or @DirtiesContext(methodMode = MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD) on MyListenerTest, but it didn't solve the problem.


Question
Why is my bean not replaced by @MockBean, but a mock is created?

btw you can add @DirtiesContext with before strategy to your MyListenerTest. You don't have to guess execution order
Also I suggest you to put a breakpoint in your listener ctor to see from where real instance coming from

@ЕвгенийРябов I tried @DirtiesContext on MyListenerTest (see my edit), but surprisingly it didn't work.

if we try to load only the required class into application-context for Integration testing. like @SpringBootTest(classes = {MyListener.class}),   and import some auto-configurations for rabbitmq setup, will that work
